# Unable to Create UDF using python in snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create snowpark UDF in python as object. Below is my code

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf
from pytorch_tabnet.tab_model import TabNetRegressor

session.clearImports()
model = TabNetRegressor()
model.load_model(model_file)

lib_test = udf(lambda: (model.device), return_type=StringType())
```

I'm getting a error like below

```
Failed to execute query 
CREATE 
TEMPORARY FUNCTION "TEST_DB"."TEST".SNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_GES3G8XHRH()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
IMPORTS=('@"TEST_DB"."TEST".SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_CR0E7FBWQ6/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.zip','@"TEST_DB"."TEST".SNOWPARK_TEMP_STAGE_CR0E7FBWQ6/TEST_DBTESTSNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_GES3G8XHRH_5843981186544791787/udf_py_1085938638.zip')
HANDLER='udf_py_1085938638.compute'


002072 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Unknown function language: PYTHON.
```

It throws error as python is not available.

I checked the packages available in information schema. It shows only scala and java. I'm not sure why python is not available in packages. How to add python to the packages? adding python will resolve this issue?

can anyone help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Python UDFs are not in production yet and are only available to selected accounts.

Please reach to Snowflake account team to have the functionality enabled.

Comment: I believe this is outdated as of my comment.